# ServiceStack: Setting Response-Type in Handler?

Tags: c#, servicestack

Using ServiceStack in stand-alone mode, I have defined a catch-all handler in my Apphost for arbitrary file names (which will just serve files out of a data directory).

Its core method is (`fi` is a `FileInfo` member variable, and `ExtensionContentType` is a `Dictionary` from the extension to the MIME type):

```
public class StaticFileHandler : EndpointHandlerBase
{
    protected static readonly Dictionary<string, string> ExtensionContentType;

    protected FileInfo fi;

    static StaticFileHandler()
    {
        ExtensionContentType = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) 
        {
            { ".text", "text/plain" },
            { ".js", "text/javascript" },
            { ".css", "text/css" },
            { ".html", "text/html" },
            { ".htm", "text/html" },
            { ".png", "image/png" },
            { ".ico", "image/x-icon" },
            { ".gif", "image/gif" },
            { ".bmp", "image/bmp" },
            { ".jpg", "image/jpeg" }
        };
    }

    public string BaseDirectory { protected set; get; }
    public string Prefix { protected set; get; }

    public StaticFileHandler(string baseDirectory, string prefix)
    {
        BaseDirectory = baseDirectory;
        Prefix = prefix;
    }

    private StaticFileHandler(FileInfo fi)
    {
        this.fi = fi;
    }

    public static StaticFileHandler Factory(string baseDirectory, string prefix, string pathInfo)
    {
        if (!pathInfo.StartsWith(prefix, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            return null;
        }

        var fn = baseDirectory + "/" + pathInfo.After(prefix.Length);

        Console.Write("StaticFileHandler.Factory fn=" + fn);

        Console.WriteLine("AbsoluteUri={0}", pathInfo);

        var fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(fn);

        if (!fi.Exists)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return new StaticFileHandler(fi);
    }

    public override void ProcessRequest(IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes, string operationName)
    {
        using (var source = new System.IO.FileStream(fi.FullName, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
        {
            source.CopyTo(httpRes.OutputStream);
            //var bytes = source.ReadAllBytes();
            //httpRes.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }

        // timeStamp = fi.LastWriteTime;                        

        httpRes.AddHeader("Date", DateTime.Now.ToString("R"));
        httpRes.AddHeader("Content-Type", ExtensionContentType.Safeget(fi.Extension) ?? "text/plain");
        //httpRes.ContentType = ExtensionContentType.Safeget(fi.Extension, "text/plain");
    }

    public override object CreateRequest(IHttpRequest request, string operationName)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override object GetResponse(IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes, object request)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The actual HTTP Response-Type header is not being set when I run with either the line marked method 1 or method 2 active.  Debugging with IE9 developer tools shows that no response-type is being set at all.

What is the proper method to set the content type (and stream content) from a catch-all handler?

This is not a standard service, so I cannot just return a customized `IHttpResponse` which seems to be the normal method for services.

Additional Info:  The Date header is not being set either...

Comment: What class/method is your ProcessRequest method overriding? I thought it would be AppHostHttpListenerBase.ProcessRequest but your example accepts more parameters. Also, you could try calling httpRes.EndServiceStackRequest() to end the request.

Comment: @paaschpa I have updated the source code to include the full class.   It is inheriting from `EndpointHandlerBase`.  The response is being sent to the browser just fine, except that my custom headers are not within it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is with this line `source.CopyTo(httpRes.OutputStream);`

The headers should populate if you do something like

```
public override void ProcessRequest(IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes, string operationName)
{
    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fi.FullName);                   
    httpRes.AddHeader("Date", DateTime.Now.ToString("R"));
    httpRes.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    httpRes.AddHeader("TestHeader", "SomeValue");
    httpRes.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

**Simple console app for testing answer**

Initialize ServiceStack AppHost and run it within a console:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var appHost = new AppHost();
        appHost.Init();
        appHost.Start("http://*:1337/");
        System.Console.WriteLine("Listening on http://localhost:1337/ ...");
        System.Console.ReadLine();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
    }
}
```

Some dummy services...not really necessary for this answer:

```
[Route("/Hello/{Name}")]
public class Hello
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class HelloService : Service
{
    public string Any(Hello request)
    {
        return request.Name;
    }
}
```

Configure AppHost and add the 'code under test' to CatchAllHanders:

```
public class AppHost : AppHostHttpListenerBase
{
    public AppHost() : base("Test Console", typeof(AppHost).Assembly) { }

    public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
    {
        CatchAllHandlers.Add(StaticFileHandler.Factory);
    }

}
```

Modified 'code under test' - mainly need to get to ProcessRequest() and return a file:

```
public class StaticFileHandler : EndpointHandlerBase
{
    protected static readonly Dictionary<string, string> ExtensionContentType;

    protected FileInfo fi;

    static StaticFileHandler()
    {
        ExtensionContentType = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) 
    {
        { ".text", "text/plain" },
        { ".js", "text/javascript" },
        { ".css", "text/css" },
        { ".html", "text/html" },
        { ".htm", "text/html" },
        { ".png", "image/png" },
        { ".ico", "image/x-icon" },
        { ".gif", "image/gif" },
        { ".bmp", "image/bmp" },
        { ".jpg", "image/jpeg" }
    };
    }

    public string BaseDirectory { protected set; get; }
    public string Prefix { protected set; get; }

    public StaticFileHandler(string baseDirectory, string prefix)
    {
        BaseDirectory = baseDirectory;
        Prefix = prefix;
    }

    private StaticFileHandler(FileInfo fi)
    {
        this.fi = fi;
    }

    public static StaticFileHandler Factory(string baseDirectory, string prefix, string pathInfo)
    {
        return new StaticFileHandler(new FileInfo(@"C:\Test.xml"));
    }

    public override void ProcessRequest(IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes, string operationName)
    {
        var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fi.FullName);

        httpRes.AddHeader("Date", DateTime.Now.ToString("R"));
        httpRes.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
        httpRes.AddHeader("Test", "SetThis");

        httpRes.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }

    public override object CreateRequest(IHttpRequest request, string operationName)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override object GetResponse(IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes, object request)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I already have AddHeader() calls, and they don't work.  Or are you suggesting that this is order dependent.

Comment: Tried putting the `AddHeader` calls before the writing of the content stream; no change in behavior.

Comment: Did you remove the source.CopyTo(httpRes.OutputStream); call? I added my full test which is a modified version of your example within a simple console AppHost.

Comment: No I did not, but CopyTo does the byte copy under the hood in .NET 4.5.   Is there some reason to suspect it is related to the problem?

Comment: I take that back after restoring pre-CopyTo code; cleared the browser cache.  It does seem to be related to `CopyTo` which is or should be a bug.

Comment: @paaschpa Hey Pat, you should chunckify and separate your source code with comments so it lays it all out in 1 page and prevents scrolling.

Comment: @paaschpa much better - show the world your beautiful SS code :) Already +1'd, but I'd +2 if they let me!